# upload image with javascript vanilla and laravel 10

Tags: javascript, laravel, file-upload

i´m trying to upload image to my server, with vanilla and laravel 10. in other occasions i can upload my images, with this way, but now i don´t know, but i can´t.

to build my logic, i´m using:

```
let serialNumber = document.getElementById('serialNumber');
serialNumber.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
    let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;

    let formData = new FormData(); 
    formData.append("file", document.getElementById('serialNumber').files[0]);          
    fetch('/installator/saveInstallationImage', {
      method: "POST", 
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'X-CSRF-Token': token,
      },
      body: formData,
    }).then(response => response.text())
      .then(success => "")
      .catch(error => ""); 

});
```

And in my controller:

```
dd($request->file('pic'));
```

this `dd()`, always return null and i don´t know that i´m doing bad...

Anybody can help me? sorry for my bad english and thank you for help

Comment: your `Content-Type` header should be `multipart/form-data`